# Devise confirmation token invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My problem is unrelated to the transition to Devise 3.1+, I already use the `@token` variable in my email view.

The problem is, the confirmation token that is sent via email is not the good one. If I try to do this on the console

```
u = User.last.send_confirmation_instructions
the_token_from_the_email = xxx #a copy paste from the email
token_digest = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :confirmation_token, the_token_from_the_email)
u.confirmation_token == token_digest
# false
```

It fails... Any idea what might cause this?

The token in the email looks like `3D7vDawAysHXKmM6YS-Mhb`
The token in the db/after digest looks like `6e8d045e084910d0cfb67b73679da12981221f52eeb984776f969f3c2d475937`

EDIT :

Here's what's happening

1. User clicks on sign_up, enter his login
2. We check the login against a distant LDAP, if we find him, then his entry on the distant LDAP is duplicated to our LDAP if it doesn't exist already (no DB query), and we send him an email with his new password
3. Then, an account for the user is created on the rails database if it doesn't exist already, the following commands are issued (note that a user `has_many :clients` and we check for client models in `confirmation_required?`

   ```
   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=intranet_rails_development collection=users selector={"confirmation_token"=>"IOciN4PmF4IPddFfDx3p2Q=="} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields={:_id=>1} runtime: 0.5599ms
   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=intranet_rails_development collection=users selector={"confirmation_token"=>"IOciN4PmF4IPddFfDx3p2Q=="} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields={:_id=>1} runtime: 0.3061ms
   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=intranet_rails_development command={:count=>"clients", :query=>{"user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('55744fd46a65004c95000000')}} runtime: 0.3512ms
   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=intranet_rails_development collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"confirmation_token"=>"b3606f731762a75314f52467993c09fdcd99124ca6357fca6b52a694f159cd9b"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.4727ms
   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 INSERT       database=intranet_rails_development collection=users documents=[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('55744fd46a65004c95000000'), "confirmation_token"=>"b3606f731762a75314f52467993c09fdcd99124ca6357fca6b52a694f159cd9b", "ldap_groups_cache"=>["Intervenants"], "last_ldap_groups_check"=>2015-06-07 14:06:12 UTC, "gender_cd"=>0, "login"=>"tarasiuk", "from_tpt_ldap"=>false, "tpt"=>false, "superadmin"=>false, "first_name"=>"Orest", "last_name"=>"Somename", "email"=>"blblabla@domain.fr", "updated_at"=>2015-06-07 14:06:12 UTC, "created_at"=>2015-06-07 14:06:12 UTC, "confirmation_sent_at"=>2015-06-07 14:06:13 UTC}] flags=[]
                        COMMAND      database=intranet_rails_development command={:getlasterror=>1, :w=>1} runtime: 0.5337ms
   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=intranet_rails_development command={:count=>"clients", :query=>{"user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('55744fd46a65004c95000000')}} runtime: 0.3471ms
   Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.3ms)
   ```
4. Then the confiration email is sent with token `confirmation_token=3DHJTJ34o1XKEL-EFn8B4j"`
5. Then a final query

   ```
   MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=intranet_rails_development collection=clients selector={"user_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('55744fd46a65004c95000000')} flags=[] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.6091ms
   Redirected to [address]
   Completed 302 Found in 2522ms
   ```
6. Then a GET with the confirmation token

   ```
   Started GET "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=3DHJTJ34o1XKEL-EFn8B4j" for 46.193.138.19 at 2015-06-07 16:22:53 +0200
   Processing by ConfirmationsController#show as HTML
     Parameters: {"confirmation_token"=>"3DHJTJ34o1XKEL-EFn8B4j"}
     MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 0.5095ms
     MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=intranet_rails_development collection=users selector={"$query"=>{"confirmation_token"=>"31cd2ab688b1fd94e6327856603b68873eff7031acc69137cc7d4a527360856b"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil runtime: 0.4650ms
   ```

Comment: What are the SQL statements in the log during this?  Do you have anything happening in e.g. an after_save which could be causing the user to be resaved with a new confirmation token which then doesn't match the one which has just been sent in the email?

Comment: I added the logs. I don't see anything suspicious, apart from that the confirmation token digested isn't the same as the one previously genrated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out I actually had a default value for that confirmation token that screwed everything up

`field :confirmation_token, default: SecureRandom.base64`

Then after another couple errors (including a bug introduced in Devise 3.5.1), I was finally able to make it work correctly

Comment: Cool, glad you tracked down what else was fiddling with the field.  I was going to ask for more log info and your class definition, but no need now :)  Is the bug in devise worth a separate self-answered question, or is it already on SO?

Comment: For the bug I mentionned, I have started a ticket [Issue #3624](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3624) on github